# Comparing rows and restricting duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

restrict duplicate entries in the entire row in whole excel sheet by comparing two rows, if any cell of of the two rows is different it should allow

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long

Dim j As Long


For j = 1 To 100

    For i = 1 To 100

  If Data.Cells(i, j).Value = Data.Cells(i + 1, j).Value Then



a = MsgBox("duplicates")

   document.write ("The Value of a is " & a)


    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1

  End If
Next

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What `document` is? Do you try logging in a way and this part is missing?

Comment: this is for excel file, suppose i filled a row and than again i am filling another row , if all the value are exactly same than it shouldn't allow to proceed , this code i have written but not working. whats wrong?

Comment: Firstly, try asking my question: "What `document` is?". `document.write` does not make sense in VBA... What error is raised and on what line? Not on this problematic `document`? In order to see a message try simple using `MsgBox "duplicates in range " & Data.Cells(i, j).Address & " - " & Data.Cells(i+1, j).Address`. `a = MsgBox("duplicates")` is wrong in the context you try using it. Comment `document.write...` and change the `MsgBox` part as I suggested and see what happens. Then, try explaining where you want to write something... But don't you want to check only the changed cell value?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try this piece of code, please:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
 If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("G:L")) Is Nothing Then
   If Target.Value <> "" Then
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If Cells(i, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value And i <> Target.Row Then
                MsgBox "row having same value"
                Target.Clear: Target.Select
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
   End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212908/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-comparing-rows-and-restricting-duplicates).